# Adding library compiled in MVSC 2012 to QT

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to port my project from Linux to Windows in QT. Project uses Apache Thrift libraries. I've built those Thrift libraries in MVSC 2012. It generated libthrift.lib file. For testing purposes, I've created a new MVSC 2012 project, included that library and everything works fine. However, when I'm trying to include that lib to QT project, it looks like it just won't get included. I'm getting errors like:

`"LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ..."`

Same errors were showing off in testing MVSC 2012 project, until i had included libthrift.lib. So I guess, the library doesnt want to be included. My .pro file:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = qtthrifttest
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -llibthrift

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\b\Desktop\boost_1_55_0
LIBS += -LC:/Users/b/Desktop/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/ -llibboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-1_55 -llibboost_system-vc110-mt-1_55 -llibboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_55
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/b/Desktop/thrift-0.9.1/lib/cpp/src
LIBS += -LC:/Users/b/Desktop/ -llibthrift


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I have libthrift.lib file on Desktop and in QT project tree, but it doesn't help. Same error with MinGW 4.8 32bit and MSVC2012 64bit. I'm using Qt 5.2.1.

How could I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your project file seemingly includes the library multiple times. The first LIBS line is unnecessary. Make sure that there exists `C:\Users\b\Desktop\libthrift.lib` (that's what you declare to exist!). Also make sure that the library is compiled to be binary compatible with the compiler settings used by Qt. You also should verify with the library file itself that the relevant symbols are indeed present.

Comment: Might also be worth trying to specify -lthrift. Most of the time, qmake will add the "lib" part itself.